# Django - not getting the queries correct

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is the scenario now:

Admin (leader of the group) logs in to see all the members who are in admins group. 
But what admin gets is members from all other groups when admin only
want to see members who are in admins group.

I only want admin to see members in his group.

Still a newbie so appreciate your help!

admin\models.py

```
class Administrator(AbstractUser):
    ...
    asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Administrator'
```

member\models.py

```
from pl.admin.models import Administrator

class Member(models.Model):
    member_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Member'

class Association(models.Model):
    asocnumber = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Association'


class member_asoc(models.Model):
    asocnumber = models.OneToOneField(Association)
    member_no = models.OneToOneField(Member)
    user = models.OneToOneField(Administrator)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'member_asoc'
```

Views.py

```
from django.db.models import F

class member_overview(ListView):

    model = Member
    template_name = 'member/member_overview.html'
    member_asoc.objects.filter(user__asoc_name=F('member_no__asoc_name'))
```

Let me know if you need more info.